# Is there a way to assign a label to a multi-select column in Quasar q-table instead of the checkbox?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, qtableview, quasar

I would like to asign a label to a multiple selection column in Quasar instead of the default 'checkbox select all'.

This is my code:

```
<q-table :rows="rows" :columns="columns" dense flat row-key="id" selection="multiple" v-model:selected="selected" hide-pagination/
```

This is a screenshot of the table:

[table with multi select column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5xGC.png)

What I want is to know if there is a way to add a label to this field, just like the label 'Row Name' of the second column.

Comment: you didn't post your columns. QTableColumn has a label field where you can put whatever you like to show.

Comment: Try to add live demo to your code or add all table's code with data linked to it as source.